# ClassNotFoundException thrown by Hibernate buildSessionFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jdbc

I am learning hibernate for the first time so unable to find the error.
The student007 table is created in the database then i executed the client class. By analyzing the error what i understand is there is a problem with the sessionfactory part. also there is an error with the oracle driver saying class not found exception
**student.hbm.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-mapping>

        <class name="beans.Student" table="student007" schema="system">

            <id name="id" column="sid"/>
            <property name="name" column="sname"/>
            <property name="email" column="semail"/>
            <property name="marks" column="smarks"/>

        </class>

    </hibernate-mapping>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="connection.username">system</property>
        <property name="connection.password">manager</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <mapping resource="resource/student.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**client.java**

```
package test;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import beans.Student;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student st = new Student();
        st.setId(111);
        st.setName("Ishan");
        st.setEmail("abx@gmail.com");
        st.setMarks(90);

        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("resource/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        //The error appears to be in the above line while building the session factory.
        Session s = sf.openSession();
        s.save(st);
        s.beginTransaction().commit();
        s.evict(st);


    }
}
```

**student.java**

```
package beans;

public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int marks;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(int marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }

    public Student() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


}
```

**I am getting this error please help**

```
Jan 16, 2017 7:10:09 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.6.Final}
Jan 16, 2017 7:10:09 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 16, 2017 7:10:10 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Jan 16, 2017 7:10:10 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at test.Client.main(Client.java:21)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:336)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please change to the title of you question to something more specific regarding your problem. This makes it easier for people with similar issues to find your post. You can describe your setup in the question itself. Thank you.

Comment: The class name `oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver` is not a valid class name, you need to use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` (note the capital O in Oracle).

Answer (score 0):

The exception message says it all: `Could not load requested class : oracle.jdbc.oracleDriver`

So the first thing I check if you misspelled the name of the driver and you really do. The class names starts with upper-case letters.
The correct name of the driver should be: `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`.